# Developer used HTML form tag as XML root tag. Can't escape

Tags: html, xml, curl, xml-parsing

I'm pulling data from a url string thats converting to XML. I have it placed on my webpage and most of it is displaying as expected. But the developer in their wisdom used an HTML tag as an XML tag `<option>`.

I can't share the whole thing but it's basically this url string displaying the xml below:

```
http://private.com/webservice6.asp?c=00000000&p=Int0000000&stock_symbols=AAPL,GE&classes=BOD,,OPTION&from=5/1/2021&to=6/1/2021&v=2&o=EVENTS
```

Its outputting like this:

```
<option>
  <event_id>4ICO1KYD</event_id>
  <company_id>1084</company_id>
</option>
```

So the browser thinks its an HTML webform select option. It's displaying the data but as one option block and I can't target the sub tags.

I have no control of the xml markup.
Is there any way of escaping or wrapping the whole thing to tell the browser to treat it as xml vs html?

Comment: Couple of questions:
 - What language are you using to parse the XML?
 - What aren't you able to share, the XML or the actual API?
If you're trying to parse an API response the <option> tag shouldn't matter (it could easily be ignored, removed or replaced if need be), and you shouldn't be reading it through a browser.
Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: I'm using a cURL script on a PHP page. Using the enchilada api. It's for a financial institution and not allowed to share the info at this time. If we shouldn't be reading it through a browser how should we be reading it? XML is not my specialty.